# Loading dynamic images on an bootstrap modal with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I/m trying to load dynamic images on a bootstrap modal with ajax when a user clicks on different links on a page. Each link has an **data-id** that is used to show its relevant image in the modal body. It works fine for the first couple of links but starts to misbehave after 4-5 clicks. Later it starts showing previously loaded images when a link is clicked and the relevant image is shown after several seconds of the modal being triggered. Can anyone help me what I'm doing wrong with my code below:

My JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).on('click', '.viewPhoto', function(e){        
        e.preventDefault();
        var pid = $(this).data('id');   // it will get id of clicked row

        $("#photoContent").html("Please Wait...");

        $.ajax({
            url: "URL OF PAGE",
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'pid='+pid,
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#photoContent').html(data); // load response    
        })
        .fail(function(){
            $('#photoContent ').html('Error');
        });      

    });                
});
```

And my modal HTML is:

```
<div id="viewPhotoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
     <div class="modal-content" >
        <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
           </button>
           <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="photoContent"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the HTML of Link is:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-id="12345" class="viewPhoto" data-target="#viewPhotoModal">View Image</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use cache: false in your ajax command.

Comment: you should read this section: https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5 - i would try to use another attribute. or attr('data-id');

Comment: Andreas Otterstein, thanks for letting me try a bit differently. Actually i figured out the problem was not in my code, it was because my main js file was included twice in the same page. Once I got rid of one of them, it worked like a charm..